# How to paste a Shape after existing Shapes in Excel Sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, shapes

I want to copy a Shape and paste it a Sheet already containing one or more Shapes. I tried using the following simple code :

```
myShape.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Paste
```

But it pastes it above the existing Shapes in the Sheet ...

Is there a solution to detect the end of the existing shapes or to paste directly after ?
Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myShape As Shape

    Set myShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1")

    myShape.Copy

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    With Selection
        .Top = myShape.Height + 10
        .Left = myShape.Left
    End With
End Sub
```

If there are more shapes then you will have to loop through all the shapes and then find the last shape and take that shape's `.Top` and `.Height` into consideration.

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim myShape As Shape, shp As Shape
    Dim sHeight As Double, sTopp As Double

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Top > sTopp Then
            sTopp = shp.Top
            sHeight = shp.Height
        End If
    Next

    Set myShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1")

    myShape.Copy

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    With Selection
        .Top = sTopp + sHeight + 10
        .Left = myShape.Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what i wanted : Detect the Shape Height, Width ... so i can manage its position in the Sheet